# How to install driver for ATI Rage 128 Pro Ultra TF?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, graphics, amd-graphics-card

This is the driver in question, it promises to be the end of my graphics troubles with my old Rage 128 card.

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5Mzk

The only trouble is, I'm not sure how to install the driver?

I'm running Ununtu 12.04.

Comment: First of all, this card is *ancient*, and you should really just upgrade. But if you absolutely insist, you "just" have to compile the Xorg/Mesa/libdrm/kernel graphics stack from source, so that you're using a version at least as recent as the version that contained those changes. If you'll note, that article was published almost on the exact day when Ubuntu 12.04 (April, 2012) was released; Ubuntu usually stops pulling in upstream changes about 3 months prior to release. So there's no way that would have made it into Ubuntu 12.04. Maybe it's in 12.10, but I don't know. Try it!

Comment: Also, if your CPU is as old as your graphics card, compiling the graphics stack will probably take you about 3 days of just waiting for your computer, whereas a modern, low-end box could compile it in about 30 minutes. So you really should just try Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 Alpha and see if it has the updated driver. 12.04 isn't obsolete, but it isn't the latest version of Ubuntu, either.

Comment: I've already tried 12.10 however there was a lovely notice upon startup saying that the graphics card is not supported, and that I should try 12.04 LTS...

Comment: Looks like you need to get the sources, apply [this patch](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2012-April/030747.html) and compile.

Comment: You're also not likely to be able to run a composite desktop very well. Might want to consider a 'lower' end DE like xfce or even openbox

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, where do I get the sources, as much as I can do with ubuntu I'm not that well versed with source codes... And with what do I compile?

Comment: Providing instructions to a beginner to compile Xorg related stuff is like trying to teach someone who doesn't speak any Japanese how to memorize the words they need to learn to function in Japan. *It doesn't work* because if you think of 50 words to teach them, they'll really, really need that 51st word that they have no idea about because they didn't take the time to learn the *concepts* and actually learn it, they just memorized (by rote) a few pieces of information. So the moral is, *don't* try to memorize things; learn how to program and compile source *in general* first.

Comment: Instead of trying to compile anything, I'd say just try Lubuntu, which uses LXDE. It can work in pure software rendering. The ATI RAGE card is definitely not going to support any compositing because its OpenGL support is just too old. So don't even worry about 3D driver support, just use it like a regular non-accelerated SVGA card.

Comment: Ok I'll give Lubuntu a go, I have tried it before on a different machine.